# How I can use a string from a xml for a string variable in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, powershell, securestring

Hi I have a xml file with two values.

The first value is the username for Powershell
The second value is the password as securestring for powershell

Now I want to read this values and set this for the variables string ps_user and SecureString ps_password

My Question is now how I can use the SecureString Value.

**here my xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

<Credential>
  <User value="tarasov" />
  <SecurePassword value="0d08c9ddf0004800000a0000340b62f9d614" />
</Credential>
```

here my c# code:

```
private string GetPowershellCredentials(string path, string attribute) 
        {
            XDocument document;
            string value = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                document = XDocument.Load(path);

                value = document.Element("Credential").Element(attribute).Attribute("value").Value;

                return value;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                document = null;
            }
        }
```

**example:**

```
> string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Powershell_credentials.xml");

> string ps_user = GetPowershellCredentials(path, "User"); // It works

> SecureString ps_password  = GetPowershellCredentials(path,"SecurePassword"); // this not :((
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ist because your GetPowershellCredentials return a string. This couldn't get converted automatically. If you need a Secure String you could use something like this:

```
public static SecureString ToSecureString(string source)
{
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
            return null;
      else
      {
            SecureString result = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in source.ToCharArray())
                result.AppendChar(c);
            return result;
      }
}
```

and this:

```
SecureString ps_password  = ToSecureString(GetPowershellCredentials(path, "SecurePassword"));
```

Comment: but the value in my xml is the securestring

Comment: (Fehler bei SSPI-Aufruf, siehe interne Ausnahme.) in english -> error by SSPI Call ,look at intern Execption ...

Comment: I think Secure Strings are not made for saving them into files an read them from there. Maybe try to use another encryption and save the encrypted Password in your XML. Then you just need to convert the decrypted password to the Secure String. Give it a try. Und viel Glück dabei!